# checking router.isActive on nested Routes in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to check routes with Router.isActive

If the current route is /animals/edit

```
(router.isActive('/animals/edit')
```

is true.

But if the current route is /animals/edit/23

```
(router.isActive('/animals/edit/')
```

is false.

How can I make a route that encompasses trailing params?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Solved it by matching the route using `router.getCurrentLocation().pathname`.

In your example, the following should do it:

```
const parentPathname = '/animals/edit';
const currentPathname = router.getCurrentLocation().pathname;
const isActive = currentPathname.indexOf(parentPathname) !== -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible with `router.isActive` as it doesn't support path params (i.e. `router.isActive('/animals/edit/:number')`).

As an alternative, using React Router v4's [matchPath](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath) you could do:

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

const match = matchPath(currentPath, {
  path: '/animals/edit(/:number)',
  exact: true,
  strict: false
})
```